# Angular-Breeze $location Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, breeze

I have a page within my angular site that allows the user to run reports based on multiple criteria (think: employeeId, eventId, fromDate, toDate, etc.). After the user has selected the parameters they want to report on, they click the submit button and are presented (on the same page) with a list of search results matching the criteria they selected. They can then click on one of the search results to be taken to the detail page for that item.

My problem is that when the user then clicks the back button, they are returned to the '/reports' url - and none of their search parameters or results are persisted. I'd like them to be returned to the page with the state that existed when they clicked on the detail row (i.e. '/reports?employeeId=2&eventId=7') and am looking for a "best practices" pattern for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a routing library, either `ngRoute` which Angular provides for you or a third-party one like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

If you're using the `ngRoute` module, you should be able to include a service defined in it called [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams) that exposes the current route's parameters as an object. If you're using `ui-router`, you could use [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

The actual persistence of the route parameters as you navigate between pages and click the back button is handled by the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) service using the [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) browser API.

To better understand how routing works in Angular, check out this [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) on the Angular site.

Answer (score -1):

You can store this piece of information using HTML5 Web Storage API. Look for some examples here http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

So you can store a dictionary like collection in the localstorage which maps each View (or page if you will) to the values that it handles.

For example, you can store an object like the following:

```
data = {
    reportPage: {
        employeeId: 2,
        eventId: 7,
        ...
    }
}
```

Then when you click the back-button, you can pre-load this data in you activate method, for example.